# Http post request in swift 3 for multiple parameters

Tags: ios, swift, http, swift3, httprequest

I am really new to Swift, in my app I am trying to do a POST request.

Url looks like following

https://example.com/login/auto/uid/5465656/hash/9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25/preset/986tzugh76rtzu00fg

following is my code

```
    let parameters = ["/uid/": "12234353", "/hash/": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25", "/preset/":"986tzugh76rtzu00fg"]as Dictionary<String, String>


    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/login/auto/") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }.resume()
```

I am getting the following error

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Could any one please help me with what I am doing wrong in the code, I am afraid that I am not sending multiple parameters correctly.

I will appreciate answers with examples if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be because there are duplicates in your parameters. Dictionary keys are supposed to be unique.

In `let parameters = ["/uid/": "12234353", "/hash/": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25", "/hash/":986tzugh76rtzu00fg]as Dictionary<String, String>` you have 2 instance of `"\hash\"`. Also type for `"/hash/":986tzugh76rtzu00fg]as` might give you an error as its supposed to be `String`.

Try this code:

```
let parameters = ["/uid/": "12234353", "/hash/": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25", "/preset/":"986tzugh76rtzu00fg"] as Dictionary<String, String>

guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/login/auto/") else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
request.httpBody = httpBody

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }

    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    }.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just edited my question, I am getting same error after correcting the duplicate paramater issue.

Comment: again value for your `/preset/` is not a `String` and so this should not compile. Try this `let parameters = ["/uid/": "12234353", "/hash/": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25", "/preset/":"986tzugh76rtzu00fg"] as Dictionary<String, String>`

Comment: thank you so much for reply, could you please have a look at my comment above on the other answer, I will really appreciate some help regarding that

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that httpBody is being set correctly. Using your exact code from above I got 3 errors that I needed to fix.

1. Second hash in parameters is not enclosed in double quotes
2. You cannot have two keys the same in the dictionary. So I had to remove the second hash.
3. Your escaping is wrong, "/ doesn't work for me. I removed all slashes.

Once I done that, I got this as the httpBody, which should work.

```
let parameters = ["uid": "12234353", "hash": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25"] as Dictionary<String, String>

let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

let string = String(data: httpBody!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(string)

Optional("{\"hash\":\"9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25\",\"uid\":\"12234353\"}")
```

**UPDATED** Based on conversation below. User needed to generate a URL with these params rather than use headers

```
let baseUrl = "https://example.com/login/auto"

let parameters = ["uid": "12234353", "hash": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var queryString = ""
for (key, value) in parameters {
    queryString += "/\(key)/\(value)"
}
print(queryString)
// output /hash/9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25/uid/12234353

print("\(baseUrl)\(queryString)")
// output https://example.com/login/auto/hash/9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25/uid/12234353
```

**UPDATE:**

To make the parameters dynamic, just create an empty dictionary and add keys and values as required

```
let baseUrl = "https://example.com/login/auto"

var parameters = [String:String]()
parameters["uid"] = "12234353"
parameters["hash"] = "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25"

var queryString = ""
for (key, value) in parameters {
    queryString += "/\(key)/\(value)"
}

let urlString = "\(baseUrl)\(queryString)"
let url = URL(string: urlString)
```

Comment: The slash character in keys is working for me. That doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: `"/uid/"` the first slash here is after the quote?

Comment: I corrected parameters for Http body as follow                                         let parameters = ["uid": "12234353", "hash": "9530cf040a49fba786100a44f913ad25", "preset" : "c3VybmFtZT1Tb25uYXRpJmdlbmRlcj0xJmVtYWlsPW1hc3NpbW8uc29ubmF0aUB0aW4uaXQ="]as Dictionary<String, String>                                           I am still getting  the same error as before which I initially highlighted in my question.

Comment: I am just wondering if I also have to add / with all the parameters as it can be seen in the original url above, That is the point where I am really confused or is it something which has to be corrected at server end as I am trying to connect my app through a web view to a third party server. They told me If the url at my side is correct then a webpage will be easily loaded in web view in the app (Original url is provided by them which I mentioned in the question).

Comment: the JSONSerlialisation should add them for you already, I didn't put them in my dictionary, but the output had them, see my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thats helpful :). But parameters have forward slashes before and after like  /uid/  in original url. The answer above by you show back slahses with parameters hash\. It will be just great if you can please help me here

Comment: ohhh you need to put the parameters in the URL! not headers. Ok I missed that completely. Let me remove this answer and update correct solution

Comment: exactly parameters in Url, that will be perfect.

Comment: I updated answer. I'll see if I can find a better solution shortly. but that will work. I had to be quick because I am leaving office now. You dont need to set httpBody or HTTP headers

Comment: Hi again, is there any possibility that I can post dynamic parameters in the using http request. as in real case uid is unique for every new user and depending on that hash will be unique to. I am already done with the part where I am getting unique uid for and hash for every user. now I am struggling how to pass these dynamic parameters to the url. do I really need to use a http request here. scenario is when I send the url with these dynamic parameters (For every user), a webpage will be loaded in my app in the web view

Comment: both did and hash are string values

Comment: using the function i have above to generate the url based off the parameters it should be easy, then just load the url in webview

Comment: I just tried to write the http body like below                                                        let bodyData = "/uid/" + uid! + "/hash/" + hash!                                             which gives me exact output that I need as following                /uid/JaQqoRu3WScb4xfyMJXHkUCqI2x1/hash/e1c6d33774af75306fa241bd1af234c8                                                                                                  but I get an error when I try to load my url, so I am not sure If I am sending the parameters correctly in http body

Comment: you do not do *anything* with http body. just build the url like i do above

Comment: perfect, now I have the url using your function. But can you please tell me how can I keep the values dynamic of both parameters something like             let parameters = ["uid": \(uid) "hash": \(hash) as Dictionary<String, String>          and also if I do not use http body how can I send the complete load the complete url with parameters in my web view

Comment: I have updated my answer with some information on how to make the parameters dynamic. From what I can see all of the information you need is in the URL not the body. the httpBody field is used to send data in a POST request

Comment: thats correct, Thanks for all help, its been really useful. The last thing I want to ask how do I pass these dynamic parameters in the url after the empty dictionary something like following.                                http://example.com/login/auto/uid/(dynamic uid)/hash/(dynamic hash)                Would like to thanks again for your kind help :)

Comment: updated again, please accept answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Man you are an angel, saved my life :) Was so badly stuck with this part, and it turns out to be so simple. Thank you so much, you are just amazing, I have no words to say thanks. You have no idea how badly stuck I was with this for some weeks. Thank you so much, you just rock :). I was trying with all complicated http post requests and it turns out to be so simple, all credit goes to you. Thanks for help, support and time :)

Comment: Your welcome, I'm glad to of helped. could you mark this answer as accepted so people know the issue is resolved. good luck with the project